# Is it posible to supply executable code to an annotation for use in the processing stage?

Tags: java, annotation-processing

Is it possible for client code to supply code to an annotation that is *directly executable* by the annotation processor?

While annotations allow classes as their members, which *looks* as it should work.

```
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    Class<? extends Predicate<Element>> helper; 
}
```

Sorta like this:

```
@MyAnnotation(helper=MyHelper.class) 
public class Foo {
   // whatever here


   public static class MyHelper implements Predicate<Element> {
       @Override 
       public Boolean test(Element s) {
           // check if the Element is something you care about here;
       }
   }
}
```

At Annotation Processing Time, this client's code, is, of course, not actually available because it hasn't been compiled yet (As far as I can tell). The best you can do is reference the class they supplied and maybe do some magic [like Lombok does by injecting it into the AST](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/blob/9be867ef03b77e0455a45d22e4a8cd7c5fa9af61/src/core/lombok/javac/handlers/HandleExtensionMethod.java#L194)

Is there any kind of mechanism to have the consumer of the annotation also supply code that can be used by the annotation itself at processing time?

Comment: Not if you need that code available to do your annotation processing / not if you want that code to process stuff from the `javax.annotation` package such as Element as in your snippet. Short of lombok shenanigans.

Comment: Does the supplied code need to be in the same module or can you add it to the classpath/modulepath of the annotation processor?

Comment: If the usage of the annotation and the helper class have to be compiled together, I guess you could technically build an interpreter for the AST, or instantiate another compilation somehow, but both seems unfeasible without having a lot of resources. Besides that, you could define some DSL using some scripting language.